# Am I chaining Promises correctly or committing a sin?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have not worked with Javascript in a long time, so now promises are a new concept to me. I have some operations requiring **more than one asynchronous call** but which I want to treat as a transaction where steps do not execute if the step before failed. Currently I chain promises by nesting and **I want to return a promise to the caller**.

After reading the chaining section of Mozilla's [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) guide, I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct or equivalent to the "callback pyramid of doom".

Is there a cleaner way to do this (besides chaining with a guard check in each `then`)? Am I right in my belief that in Mozilla's example it will execute each chained `then` even when there is an error?

```
myfunction(key) => {
    return new Promise((outerResolve, outerReject) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let item = cache.get(key);
            if (item) {
                resolve(item);
            } else {
                //we didnt have the row cached, load it from store   
                chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (result) {
                    chrome.runtime.lastError
                        ? reject({ error: chrome.runtime.lastError.message })
                        : resolve(result);
                });
            }
        }).then((resolve) => {
            //Now the inner most item is resolved, we are working in the 'outer' shell
            if (resolve.error) {
                outerReject(resolve);
            } else {
                //No error, continue
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    chrome.storage.sync.get(keyBasedOnPreviousData, function (result) {
                        chrome.runtime.lastError
                            ? reject({ error: chrome.runtime.lastError.message })
                            : resolve(result);
                    });
                }).then((resolve) => {
                    //finally return the result to the caller
                    if (resolve.error) {
                        outerReject(resolve);
                    } else {
                        outerResolve(resolve);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: If you're talking about the "callback hell", then you may think about using `async await` (by eventually transpiling your code first) to make the code cleaner and easier to read or, eventually, to chain operations with function generators (that would be hard to understand, though).

Comment: `try` and `catch` on error return a `Promise.reject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsequent `then` statements are not executed (until a `catch`) when an exception is thrown. Also, `.then` returns a Promise, so you don't need to create an additional, outer Promise.

Try this example:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('first promise, resolves');
    resolve();
})
.then(() => {
    throw new Error('Something failed');
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('then after the error');
    return('result');
});

p.then(res => console.log('success: ' + res), err => console.log('error: ' + err));
```

You will not see "then after the error" in the console, because that happens after an exception is thrown. But if you comment the `throw` statement, you will get the result you expect in the Promise.

I am not sure I understand your example entirely, but I think it could be simplified like this:

```
myfunction(key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let item = cache.get(key);
        if (item) {
            resolve(item);
        } else {
            //we didnt have the row cached, load it from store   
            chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (result) {
                chrome.runtime.lastError
                    ? throw new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message)
                    : resolve(result);
            });
        }
    }).then((previousData) => {
        // keyBasedOnPreviousData is calculated based on previousData
        chrome.storage.sync.get(keyBasedOnPreviousData, function (result) {
            chrome.runtime.lastError
                ? throw new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message)
                : return result;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe this ends up returning the data, not a promise the caller can use, right?

Comment: No, it will return a Promise. Check the example above, p is really a Promise, otherwise you could not use it like one.

Comment: my question is referring the rewrite (myFunction), but I think it applies to both. Once you `return result` (which I didn't think you can do) it's no longer a promise, surely?

Comment: The returned Promise depends on what the .then handler function returns. Check out the Return value explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then .
Not super simple, but I guess it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out in the morning

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a mess. This is my attempt at rewriting. A good thing to try to avoid is `new Promise()`.

```
function chromeStorageGet(key) {    
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {

     chrome.storage.sync.get(key, result => {   
       if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
         rej(new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message))
       } else {
         res(result)
       }
     }); 

  });  
});


function myfunction(key) {

   const item = cache.get(key) ? Promise.resolve(cache.get(key)) : chromeStorageGet(key);
   return item.then( cacheResult => {
     return chromeStorageGet(keyBasedOnPreviousData);
   });

}
```

Why avoid `new Promise()`?

The reason for this is that you want to do every step with `then()`. If any error happened in *any* of the promises, every promise in the chain will fail and any subsequent `then()` will not get executed *until* there is a `catch()` handler.

Lots of promise based-code requires no error handlers, because promise-based functions always return promises and exceptions should flow all the back to the caller until there is something useful to be done with error handling.

Note that the exceptions to these 2 rules are in my `chromeStorageGet` function. A few notes here:

- `new Promise` can be a quick and easy way to convert callback code to promise code.
- It's usually a good idea to just create a little conversion layer for this callback-based code. If you need `chrome.storage.sync` in other places, maybe create a little utility that promisifies all its functions.
- If there is only 1 'flow', you can just use a series of `then()` to complete the process, but sometimes you need to conditionally do other things. Just splitting up these complicated operations in a number of different functions can really help here.

But this:

```
const result = condition ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
```

Is almost always preferred to:

```
const result = new Promise( (res, rej) => { 
  if (condition) {
    res();
  } else { 
    rej();
  }
}
```

Comment: "If any error happened in any of the promises, every promise in the chain will fail and any subsequent then() will not get executed" so I  don't need to use any try catch, I just need to wrap the error with new Error() and all remaining then() calls will be skipped? (even without 'throw'?)

Comment: `new Error` is just a better convention instead of rejecting with arbitrary objects. The remaining `then()` calls will indeed be skipped _until there is a a `catch()` call.